How to create custom @PostAuthorize Annotations that accept returnObject as annotation type?
How does one create custom @PostAuthorized annotations in Java / Kotlin on Spring?
@Service("authorizationService")
class AuthorizationLogic {
    fun decide(response: ResponseEntity<Student?>): Boolean {
        val student = response.body
        return student?.firstname == "Sachin"
    }

    companion object {
        @Bean
        fun prePostTemplateDefaults(): PrePostTemplateDefaults {
            return PrePostTemplateDefaults()
        }
    }
}


@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@PostAuthorize("@authorizationService.decide({'returnObject'})")
annotation class PostAuthorizeDecide(val value: Student)

This says Student is not allowed. The same for ResponseEntity<Student?>, and MethodSecurityExpressionOperations
Anyone, any ideas?
